# Redesigning an existing website, should I create a new Google Analytics Property or Profile

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics

We're doing a top-down redesign of an existing website.
Since there a number of years of great data we do not want to lose, should we remain within the same Property, move to a new one, or create a new profile within the same property?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same property as the old website and create an annotation for when you launch the new site. While you're in there, I'd create a new Universal Analytics property. Universal Analytucs is still in beta, but it's going to replace Google Analytics so you could get familiar with it by dual-tagging your website - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en

If you're really feeling adventurous, you can check out Google Tag Manager to manage both your Google Analytics and Universal Analytics implementations - http://www.google.com/tagmanager/